# Regex match between parenthesis and other characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the numbers between this string, I don't need to match anything after the number.

`(14,240 Reviews)`

Trying everything I know and not have any luck.

I tried this but I think its incorrect.

```
((\d){1,3})+([,][\d]{3})*([.](\d)*)?
```

Desired Results is `14,240`

Comment: `\d{1,3},\d{1,3}` works fine for me, based on the bare minimum details you've provided. Your specifications are very vague, which is why I'm leaving this in a comment instead of posting an answer.

Comment: Depends on your match criteria, e.g. do numbers need to be within `()`? etc

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/BBn050/1 seems to work as you want. What is your current output? Also what language are you using as the implementation can differ

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the parenthesis into account, you can assert `(` to the left and a `)` to the right if lookarounds are supported.

```
(?<=\()\d+(?:,\d+)*(?=[^()]*\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HiMYWY/1)

Another option is using a capture group and for example matching Review or Reviews, and then get the capture group 1 value.

```
\((\d+(?:,\d+)*) Reviews?\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ctufff/1)

Answer (score 0):

`/(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)\sReviews?/`
It will find any number inside the parathesis.

```js
const pattern = /(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)\sReviews?/;
const testStrings = [
  "(14,240 Review)",
  "(1 Review)",
  "(10 Reviews)",
  "(100 Reviews)",
  "(1,000 Reviews)",
  "(10,000 Reviews)",
  "(100,000 Reviews)",
  "(1,000,000 Reviews)",
  "(10,000,000 Reviews)",
  "(100,000,000 Reviews)",
  "(1,000,000,000 Reviews)"
];

testStrings.forEach((text) => {
  const match = text.match(pattern);
  const number = match ? match[1] : '';
  console.log(number); // prints the number extracted from each test string
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log('(14,240 Reviews)'.match(/(\d+)/g))
```